# ¿saber el auto_increment de una tabla MySQL despues de borrarse los ultimos ID`s?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Amigos, acudo a ustedes para saber quien me dice como saber el auto_increment de una tabla.

Supongamos que `id_campo` tiene 30 valores, pero después se borra unas 6 filas, quedaría en `id_campo (24)`, pero el auto_increment está en 31.

¿Existe una forma de obtener ese `auto_increment(31)` con consulta SQL sin tener que crear otra tabla que guarde el ultimo valor auto_increment de la tabla principal?

Comment: Puedes mandar la estructura de tu tabla porfavor

Comment: CREATE TABLE `r_categoria` (
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_categoria` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `r_departamento_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: ALTER TABLE `r_categoria`
  MODIFY `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=30;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Nombre de Base de Datos'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'Nombre de Tabla';
```

Comment: Eres un genio Kerepakupai, justamente eso era lo que quería.
Me sale exactamente el auto_increment que busco, los 30.
Ya me puedo quitar de la cabeza el pensar que tenía que insertar el auto_increment en otra tabla (cosas que uno hace desesperado y por no saber SQL como debe ser).

Comment: O sea, se usaría así: `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT AS last_ai
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Nombre de Base de Datos'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'Nombre de Tabla';` luego: `ALTER TABLE 'Nombre de Tabla' AUTO_INCREMENT = last_ai - 1;` para restarle 1 en hard coded. Quizá restarle el número de filas eliminadas, resultado de algún `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que se quiere es obtener el último valor de un campo auto-incremental, no el valor que está en memoria en `information_schemes`, sería mejor usar la consulta que hace el mismo `InnoDB`.

Dado:

- Tabla: `r_categoria`
- Columna auto_increment: `id_categoria`

Ejecutamos esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(id_categoria) AS ultimo 
FROM r_categoria;
```

La consulta devolvería el id del último valor existente.

Si quieres obtener el valor de un próximo nuevo valor, sólo sería cuestión de sumarle uno:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(id_categoria)+1 AS ultimo 
FROM r_categoria;
```

En ese caso, la consulta será menos costosa que tener que leer los `INFORMATION.SCHEMES`, porque se actúa directamente sobre la tabla.

Según la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html), esa es la forma en que InnoDB inicializa el contador auto-incremental:

> #### `InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT` Inicialización del contador
>
> Si especifica una columna `AUTO_INCREMENT` para una tabla `InnoDB`, el
> manejador de tabla en el diccionario de datos `InnoDB` contiene un
> contador especial llamado contador de incremento automático que se usa
> para asignar nuevos valores para la columna. Este contador se almacena
> solo en la memoria principal, no en el disco.
>
> Para inicializar un contador de incremento automático después de
> reiniciar el servidor, `InnoDB` ejecuta el equivalente de la siguiente
> instrucción en la primera inserción en una tabla que contiene una
> columna `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
>
> ```
> SELECT MAX (ai_col) FROM table_name FOR UPDATE;
> ```
>
> InnoDB incrementa el valor recuperado por la instrucción y lo asigna a
> la columna y al contador de incremento automático para la tabla. De
> forma predeterminada, el valor se incrementa en 1. Este valor
> predeterminado puede ser anulado por la configuración de configuración
> [`auto_increment_increment`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment).

Comment: Retomando el ejemplo de OP, la consulta retornaría 24 en lugar de 30, pero a final de cuentas funcionaría para una inserción

Comment: El SELECT MAX(id_categoria) ultimo FROM r_categoria;
Si agrego 30 ID's y borro los ultimos 6, ese comando de arriba solo me daría 24 y no el verdadero auto_increment(31) porque solo actua donde haya filas(ID's) existentes.
Mientras que el codigo que me dio Kerepakupai se ajusta a lo que necesito, no importa si se borra todos los datos de la tabla, el valor auto_increment seguirá ahí hasta que sea reseteado, comenzando desde 0 o si se borra la tabla.

Comment: @AngelZambrano o sea, lo que quieres es el valor que se pudo haber quedado en memoria... entonces no entendí del todo la pregunta, entendí que quería el último valor de los registros existentes.

Comment: No, ahí arriba coloqué como pregunta "¿saber el auto_increment de una tabla MySQL despues de borrarse los ultimos ID`s?"
No coloqué "¿Saber el ID del ultimo valor registrado?".
De todas maneras muchas gracias por estar atento a estos foros/debates, me han ayudado mucho.

Comment: @AngelZambrano he editado la pregunta, indicándola como una posibilidad en caso de que se quiera obtener el último id, ya que en ese caso el uso de `information_scheme` sería más costoso.

Answer (score 0):

Esta operación NO ES FUNCIONAL.

Resulta que si se borra un registro en la tabla, para el motor como tal, no lo tiene en cuenta y sigue con el ID que se supone seguía, entonces ahí es cuando no nos va a servir ese método.

```
SELECT MAX(id_categoria)+1 ultimo FROM r_categoria;
```

Comment: Entonces obtienes el auto_increment actual; lo guardas en variable `$ai` o `AS ai`; le restas 6 filas del ejemplo y realizas la query: ALTER TABLE r_categoria
AUTO_INCREMENT = ai; y listo, auto_increment actualizado! O... ¿no?